# Should I provide both English GB and US as store listing in Google Play?

Tags: android, localization, google-play

The Google Play Console gives a possibility to provide store listing in different languages. But it has duplicate languages options for different countries.

- English (United States / United Kingdom)
- Spanish (Latin America / Spain / United States)
- French (France / Canada)

I am aware of language differences in different countries, but we have the possibility to provide only single English, single Spanish and single French translation. So we spend a lot of time uploading completely the same metadata and images to different locales. Moreover, it is much harder to run localised experiments.

Do we need to upload the same content to all variations or only one for each language is enough?

The application default language is the English US and we have uploaded only Spanish Spain metadata. If the user who is using Spanish Latin America opens the application page it will be English or Spanish?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the API level.  Before Android 7 (API level 24), Android required exact matches.  So if a user had the device set for, say, es_AR (Argentinian Spanish), it would not match es_ES.

API level 24 has improved matching, and would work in the example above.  There are recommendations for how to optimize the matching process.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html for details.

Comment: This is regarding Android system itself. The question is next: Will Google Play show store listings if the locale does not match? Google Play is web service and may work with locales in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

From Android 7.0  it does fall back to one of the child languages  say if user preferred  language is fr_CH and developer provided fr_FR  then it look for resource in this order   fr_CH ---> fail ---> try Fr--> Fail -----> try children of Fr that is  fr_FR matches .

information here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support.html

Answer (score 0):

We follow the simple rule now. We use English as a default language.

- We do not provide English country-specific translations (as they will either way fallback to English).
- We add each variation for languages like French or Spanish.

Comment: So if you don't provide "es-US" for example, and someone has set this language, will it fall back to "es-ES" (because this is Spanish too) or to "en" (because this is the default language)?